# ¿Cómo eliminar filas de un DataFrame en función del año de la fecha?

Tags: python, datetime

En el siguiente código paso a **datetime** las filas de la columna 'Date', agrupo y hago la media de los datos para los que coinciden las fechas y lo divido entre 10. Mi error ocurre en la última línea de código, al intentar eliminar las filas con fecha superior a 2016 recibo un **KeyError:'Date'**. Gracias por la ayuda!

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df=df.groupby('Date').apply((np.mean))
df['Data_Value']=df['Data_Value']/10
df=df[df['Date'].dt.year < 2016]
```

Comment: Al haber hecho un `groupby('Date')` esa columna desaparece y pasa a ser el índice en el resultado. Ya que asignas ese resultado de nuevo a `df`, pierdes los valores originales. Quizás te funcione usar `df[df.index.dt.year<2016]` en la última línea

Comment: Gracias por la explicación! Me bastó con aplicar **reset_index()** a la segunda línea